# Can't get JavaScript to check for null objects

Tags: javascript

I really don't know what the issue is here. As far as I can see, the code is simple and should work fine.

```
          var Prices="";
          for (var PriceCount = 1; PriceCount <= 120; PriceCount++) {
              var CurrentPrice = "Price" + PriceCount;
              if (prevDoc.getElementById(CurrentPrice).value != null) {
                  if (Prices == "") {
                      Prices = prevDoc.getElementById(CurrentPrice).value;
                  } else {
                      Prices += "," + prevDoc.getElementById(CurrentPrice).value;
                  }
              } else {
                  break;
              }
          }
```

There could be up to 120 hidden inputs on the form.  The moment we check for an input that doesn't exist the loop should break.  My test page has two input elements that get pulled.  On the third (the null) I get this error in firebug:

```
prevDoc.getElementById(CurrentPrice) is null

 if (prevDoc.getElementById(CurrentPrice).value != null) {
```

Yes it is null...that's what the check is for ಠ_ಠ

Does any one know what I'm doing wrong?  This seems like it should be really straight forward.

EDIT:
for clarity's sake, prevDoc=window.opener.document

Comment: 1) Are you sure that `prevDoc` is not `null`? (Have you set a breakpoint in the code and looked at the value in the watch window, or used `console.log()` to output the result? 2) Are you certain that these items have `id="..."` and not `name="..."`?

Comment: Yes, its not null.  That variable was being used all over this page before I put my hands on it

Comment: The element with the name in `CurrentPrice` can't be found when you do `prevDoc.getElementById(CurrentPrice)`, therefore you get an error when you are trying to read its value. Could also be that you are not allowed to read it.

Comment: Ah, OK; I missed that. Will delete my noise, glad you got your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (prevDoc.getElementById(CurrentPrice).value != null) {
```

can be expanded to:

```
var element = prevDoc.getElementById(CurrentPrice);    
var value = element.value; /* element is null, but you're accessing .value */

if (value != null) {
```

Comment: Well I feel dumb now... Thanks for the assist :D

Answer (score 1):

value is never null.

If it is not filled in, the value would be "" or a length of zero.

If the element does not exist, you would check for the existence of the element.

```
var CurrentPrice = "Price" + PriceCount;
var elem = prevDoc.getElementById(CurrentPrice);
if (elem && elem.value != null) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (prevDoc.getElementById(CurrentPrice) !== null)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
var Prices="";
for (var PriceCount = 1; PriceCount <= 120; PriceCount++) {
    var CurrentPriceId = "Price" + PriceCount,
        CurrentPrice = prevDoc.getElementById(CurrentPriceId);

    if (CurrentPrice != null) {
        Prices = (Prices == "") ? CurrentPrice.value : (Prices + "," + CurrentPrice.value);
    }
    else break;
}
```